# "[circuit_breaking_exception] [parent]" Data too large, data for "[<http_request>]" would be error

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

After smoothly working for more than 10 months, I start getting this error on production suddenly while doing simple search queries.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "circuit_breaking_exception",
        "reason" : "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [745522124/710.9mb], which is larger than the limit of [745517875/710.9mb]",
        "bytes_wanted" : 745522124,
        "bytes_limit" : 745517875
      }
    ],
    "type" : "circuit_breaking_exception",
    "reason" : "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [745522124/710.9mb], which is larger than the limit of [745517875/710.9mb]",
    "bytes_wanted" : 745522124,
    "bytes_limit" : 745517875
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

Initially, I was getting this error while doing simple term queries when I got this **circuit_breaking_exception** error, To debug this I tried _cat/health query on elasticsearch cluster, but still, the same error, even the simplest query **localhost:9200** is giving the same error Not sure what happens to the cluster suddenly.
Her is my circuit breaker status:

```
"breakers" : {
        "request" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 639015321,
          "limit_size" : "609.4mb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 0,
          "estimated_size" : "0b",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "fielddata" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 639015321,
          "limit_size" : "609.4mb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 406826332,
          "estimated_size" : "387.9mb",
          "overhead" : 1.03,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "in_flight_requests" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 1065025536,
          "limit_size" : "1015.6mb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 560,
          "estimated_size" : "560b",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "accounting" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 1065025536,
          "limit_size" : "1015.6mb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 146387859,
          "estimated_size" : "139.6mb",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        },
        "parent" : {
          "limit_size_in_bytes" : 745517875,
          "limit_size" : "710.9mb",
          "estimated_size_in_bytes" : 553214751,
          "estimated_size" : "527.5mb",
          "overhead" : 1.0,
          "tripped" : 0
        }
      }
```

I found a similar issue here[Github Issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31197) that suggests increasing circuit breaker memory or disabling the same. But I am not sure what to choose. Please help!

Elasticsearch Version 6.3

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After some more research finally, I found a solution for this i.e

1. We should not disable circuit breaker as it might result in OOM error and eventually might crash elasticsearch.
2. dynamically increasing circuit breaker memory percentage is good but it is also a temporary solution because at the end after solution increased percentage might also fill up.
3. Finally, we have a third option i.e increase overall JVM heap size which is 1GB by default but as recommended it should be around 30-32 GB on production, also it should be less than 50% of available total memory.

For more info check this for good JVM memory configurations of elasticsearch on production, [Heap: Sizing and Swapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html)

Comment: For some reason your link points to the outdated 2.x version of ES

Comment: This is applicable for all versions, though you can navigate to recent version through this link titled Heap size settings i.e https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/important-settings.html#heap-size-settings. This doc includes many other settings which would help you configure a good production level es environment.

Comment: Yeah, but in the more recent version the export environment variable part is missing and I think it also did not work for me

Comment: @RadioControlled, export ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g", this is how you should set heap size in recent versions. 2g here is 2GB. and please keep in mind that this size should not be more than half of your total available memory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have an index with large documents, each document has **~30 KB** and more than **130 fields** (nested objects, arrays, dates and ids).
and I was searching all fields using this DSL query:

```
query_string: {
    query: term,
    analyze_wildcard: true,
    fields: ['*'], // search all fields
    fuzziness: 'AUTO'
}
```

Since full-text searches are expensive. Searching through multiple fields at once is even more expensive. Expensive in terms of computing power, not storage.

Therefore:

> The more fields a query_string or multi_match query targets, the
> slower it is. A common technique to improve search speed over multiple
> fields is to copy their values into a single field at index time, and
> then use this field at search time.

please refer to [ELK docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#search-as-few-fields-as-possible) that recommends searching as few fields as possible with the help of [copy-to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) directive.

After I changed my query to search one field:

```
    query_string: {
        query: term,
        analyze_wildcard: true,
        fields: ['search_field'] // search in one field
    }
```

everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error with my docker container so I increase the java_opts to 1GB and now it works without any error.

Here are the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '1'
services:
 elasticsearch-cont:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
   container_name: elasticsearch
   environment:
     - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
     - discovery.type=single-node
   ulimits:
     memlock:
       soft: -1
       hard: -1
   ports:
     - 9200:9200
     - 9300:9300
   networks:
     - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also have an index with large documents which store system running logs and I searched the index with all fields.  I use the Java Client API, like this:

```
TermQueryBuilder termQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery("uid", uid);        
searchSourceBuilder.query(termQueryBuilder);
```

When I changed my code like this:

```
TermQueryBuilder termQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery("uid", uid);
searchSourceBuilder.fetchField("uid");
searchSourceBuilder.fetchSource(false);
searchSourceBuilder.query(termQueryBuilder);
```

the error disappeared.