# Elasticsearch and Fluentd optimisation for log cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

we are using Elasticsearch and Fluentd for Central logging platform. below is our Config details:
*Elasticsearch Cluster:*

```
Master Nodes: 64Gb Ram, 8 CPU, 9 instances
Data Nodes: 64Gb Ram, 8 CPU, 40 instances
Coordinator Nodes: 64Gb Ram, 8Cpu, 20 instances
```

*Fluentd:* at any given time we have around 1000+ fluentd instances writing logs to Elasticsearch coordinator nodes.
and on daily basis we create around 700-800 indices and which total to 4K shards on daily basis. and we keep maximum 40K shards on cluster.
we started facing performance issue on Fluentd side, where fluentd instances fails to write logs. common issues are :

```
 1. read time out
 2. request time out
 3. {"time":"2021-07-02","level":"warn","message":"failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=9 next_retry_seconds=2021-07-02 07:23:08 265795215088800420057/274877906944000000000 +0000 chunk=\"5c61e5fa4909c276a58b2efd158b832d\" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error=\"could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\\\"logs-es-data.internal.tech\\\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\\\"http\\\"}): [429] {\\\"error\\\":{\\\"root_cause\\\":[{\\\"type\\\":\\\"circuit_breaking_exception\\\",\\\"reason\\\":\\\"[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [32274168710/30gb], which is larger than the limit of [31621696716/29.4gb], real usage: [32268504992/30gb], new bytes reserved: [5663718/5.4mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=0/0b, in_flight_requests=17598408008/16.3gb, model_inference=0/0b, accounting=0/0b]\\\",\\\"bytes_wanted\\\":32274168710,\\\"bytes_limit\\\":31621696716,\\\"durability\\\":\\\"TRANSIENT\\\"}],\\\"type\\\":\\\"circuit_breaking_exception\\\",\\\"reason\\\":\\\"[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [32274168710/30gb], which is larger than the limit of [31621696716/29.4gb], real usage: [32268504992/30gb], new bytes reserved: [5663718/5.4mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=0/0b, in_flight_requests=17598408008/16.3gb, model_inference=0/0b, accounting=0/0b]\\\",\\\"bytes_wanted\\\":32274168710,\\\"bytes_limit\\\":31621696716,\\\"durability\\\":\\\"TRANSIENT\\\"},\\\"status\\\":429}\"","worker_id":0}
```

looking for guidance on this, how we can optimise our Logs cluster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[circuit\_breaking\_exception\] \[parent\]" Data too large, data for "\[<http\_request>\]" would be error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870751/circuit-breaking-exception-parent-data-too-large-data-for-http-request)

Comment: @Azeem no, we already have 31Gb heap on server size of 64Gb Ram.

Comment: Could you please share your ElasticSearch configuration? And, what do you mean by "read timeout" error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by the looks of it, you have exhausted your parent circuit breaker limit of 95% of Heap Memory.
The error you mentioned has been mentioned in the elasticsearch docs -
[1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fix-common-cluster-issues.html#diagnose-circuit-breaker-errors
. The page also refers to a few steps you can take to Reduce JVM memory pressure, which can be helpful to reduce this error.

You can also try increasing this limit to 98%, using the dynamic command -

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "indices.breaker.total.limit" : "98%" 
  }
}
```

But I would suggest this be performance tested before applying in production.

Since your request is 30GB, which is a bit too much, for a more reliable solution, I would suggest increasing your log scrapers frequency, so that it makes more frequent posts to ES with smaller-sized data blocks.